# Setters and getters aren't accessible from custom user entity in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, hwioauthbundle

I'm trying to implement the hwioauthbundle for connecting with Google.
However, I'm facing the problem that symfony can't seem to find the method declared in the User entity - I believe it has something to do with the FOSUserBundle that I'm also using.

Here is my GoogleProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Security\User\Provider;

use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseClass;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class GoogleProvider extends BaseClass
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $property = $this->getProperty($response);
        $username = $response->getUsername();
        //on connect - get the access token and the user ID
        $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set'.ucfirst($service);
        $setter_id = $setter.'Id';
        $setter_token = $setter.'AccessToken';
        //we "disconnect" previously connected users
        if (null !== $previousUser = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($property => $username))) {
            $previousUser->$setter_id(null);
            $previousUser->$setter_token(null);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($previousUser);
        }
        //we connect current user
        $user->$setter_id($username);
        $user->$setter_token($response->getAccessToken());
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $username = $response->getUsername();

        $user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($this->getProperty($response) => $username));
        //when the user is registrating
        if (null === $user) {
            $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
            $setter = 'set'.ucfirst($service);
            $setter_id = $setter.'Id';
            $setter_token = $setter.'AccessToken';
            // create new user here
            $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
            $user->$setter_id($username);
            $user->$setter_token($response->getAccessToken());
            //I have set all requested data with the user's username
            //modify here with relevant data
            $user->setUsername($username);
            $user->setEmail($username);
            $user->setPassword($username);
            $user->setEnabled(true);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
            return $user;
        }
        //if user exists - go with the HWIOAuth way
        $user = parent::loadUserByOAuthUserResponse($response);
        $serviceName = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($serviceName) . 'AccessToken';
        //update access token
        $user->$setter($response->getAccessToken());
        return $user;
    }
}
```

And here is FOSUBUserProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Connect\AccountConnectorInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\Exception\AccountNotLinkedException;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

class FOSUBUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface, AccountConnectorInterface, OAuthAwareUserProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var UserManagerInterface
     */
    protected $userManager;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $properties = array(
        'identifier' => 'id',
    );

    /**
     * @var PropertyAccessor
     */
    protected $accessor;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param UserManagerInterface $userManager FOSUB user provider.
     * @param array                $properties  Property mapping.
     */
    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager, array $properties)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->properties  = array_merge($this->properties, $properties);
        $this->accessor    = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        // Compatibility with FOSUserBundle < 2.0
        if (class_exists('FOS\UserBundle\Form\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler')) {
            return $this->userManager->loadUserByUsername($username);
        }

        return $this->userManager->findUserByUsername($username);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $username = $response->getUsername();

        $user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($this->getProperty($response) => $username));
        if (null === $user || null === $username) {
            throw new AccountNotLinkedException(sprintf("User '%s' not found.", $username));
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Expected an instance of FOS\UserBundle\Model\User, but got "%s".', get_class($user)));
        }

        $property = $this->getProperty($response);

        if (!$this->accessor->isWritable($user, $property)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf("Class '%s' must have defined setter method for property: '%s'.", get_class($user), $property));
        }

        $username = $response->getUsername();

        if (null !== $previousUser = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($property => $username))) {
            $this->accessor->setValue($previousUser, $property, null);

            $this->userManager->updateUser($previousUser);
        }

        $this->accessor->setValue($user, $property, $username);

        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        // Compatibility with FOSUserBundle < 2.0
        if (class_exists('FOS\UserBundle\Form\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler')) {
            return $this->userManager->refreshUser($user);
        }

        $identifier = $this->properties['identifier'];
        if (!$user instanceof User || !$this->accessor->isReadable($user, $identifier)) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Expected an instance of FOS\UserBundle\Model\User, but got "%s".', get_class($user)));
        }

        $userId = $this->accessor->getValue($user, $identifier);
        if (null === $user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($identifier => $userId))) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('User with ID "%d" could not be reloaded.', $userId));
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        $userClass = $this->userManager->getClass();

        return $userClass === $class || is_subclass_of($class, $userClass);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the property for the response.
     *
     * @param UserResponseInterface $response
     *
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    protected function getProperty(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $resourceOwnerName = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();

        if (!isset($this->properties[$resourceOwnerName])) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf("No property defined for entity for resource owner '%s'.", $resourceOwnerName));
        }

        return $this->properties[$resourceOwnerName];
    }
}
```

And here is my service:

```
parameters:
    my_user_provider.class: AppBundle\Security\User\Provider\GoogleProvider

services:
    my_user_provider:
        class: "%my_user_provider.class%"
        #this is the place where the properties are passed to the UserProvider - see config.yml
        arguments: [@fos_user.user_manager,{facebook: facebook_id, google: google_id}]
```

Here is my User entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $facebook_id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $facebookAccessToken;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $google_id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $googleAccessToken;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $keyword;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->keyword = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return User
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set facebook_id
     *
     * @param integer $facebookId
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFacebookId($facebookId)
    {
        $this->facebook_id = $facebookId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get facebook_id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getFacebookId()
    {
        return $this->facebook_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set facebookAccessToken
     *
     * @param string $facebookAccessToken
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFacebookAccessToken($facebookAccessToken)
    {
        $this->facebookAccessToken = $facebookAccessToken;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get facebookAccessToken
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFacebookAccessToken()
    {
        return $this->facebookAccessToken;
    }

    /**
     * Set google_id
     *
     * @param integer $googleId
     * @return User
     */
    public function setGoogleId($googleId)
    {
        $this->google_id = $googleId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get google_id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getGoogleId()
    {
        return $this->google_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set googleAccessToken
     *
     * @param string $googleAccessToken
     * @return User
     */
    public function setGoogleAccessToken($googleAccessToken)
    {
        $this->googleAccessToken = $googleAccessToken;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get googleAccessToken
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getGoogleAccessToken()
    {
        return $this->googleAccessToken;
    }

    /**
     * Add keyword
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Keyword $keyword
     * @return User
     */
    public function addKeyword(\AppBundle\Entity\Keyword $keyword)
    {
        $this->keyword[] = $keyword;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove keyword
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Keyword $keyword
     */
    public function removeKeyword(\AppBundle\Entity\Keyword $keyword)
    {
        $this->keyword->removeElement($keyword);
    }

    /**
     * Get keyword
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getKeyword()
    {
        return $this->keyword;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? 
I works when I do:

```
$user->setUsername($username);
$user->setEmail($username);
$user->setPassword($username);
$user->setEnabled(true);
```

But for instance I can't do:

```
$user->setGoogleId(123);
```

but I guess it is because they are not in my User entity, but in FOSUserBundle.
It seems like it doesn't extend my User entity.

I appreciate all kinds of help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add every method you expect to work in your User entity. There is no magic. So, add a `setFacebookId()`, `setFacebookAccessToken()`, etc. Indeed, you could even add a `setGoogleId()`, but there is no property called `$googleId` in your entity.